# Scraping Amazon reviews, cannot exclude paid reviews

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the number of stars each reviewer gives a product. I noticed some reviewers are "Vine Voices" or paid reviewers. They rarely give 4, mostly 5 stars. Therefore, I'd like to exclude them.

The way I do this is by tagging them "Paid" or "Not-paid" if a review is marked with "a-color-success a-text-bold" tag.

I can't seem to append any "Paid" tags into the vine variable. How come?

Only those reviews who are written by a Vine Voice, has the tag, those who don't does not have the tag in "paid".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}

rating_list = [] 
date_list = []
vine = []

for num in range(1,12):
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/Jabra-Wireless-Noise-Canceling-Headphones-Built/product-reviews/B07RS8B5HV/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber={}&sortBy=recent".format(num)

    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    for ratings in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-hook": "review"}):     
        submission_date = ratings.find("span", {'data-hook':'review-date'}).text
        rating = ratings.find('i', attrs={"data-hook": "review-star-rating"}).text
        paid = ratings.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-color-success a-text-bold"})

        if paid in ratings:
             vine.append("Paid")
        else:
            vine.append("Not-paid")

            date_list.append(submission_date)
            rating_list.append(rating)

            data = {'Rating':rating_list, 'Date':date_list, "Paid":vine}
        time.sleep(2)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False)
print(df)
```

This is what I get so far.
Review 2 and 3 are Vine Voice, but they are getting tagged as Not-Paid, but should be Paid.

```
0    5.0 out of 5 stars 2019-09-18  Not-paid
1    4.0 out of 5 stars 2019-09-13  Not-paid
2    5.0 out of 5 stars 2019-09-12  Not-paid
3    5.0 out of 5 stars 2019-09-11  Not-paid
4    5.0 out of 5 stars 2019-09-10  Not-paid
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comparing element with element and that is why its getting to else condition always.
I have made changes and compared text with text and it is working fine.Check the below code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}

rating_list = []
date_list = []
vine = []

for num in range(1,12):
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/Jabra-Wireless-Noise-Canceling-Headphones-Built/product-reviews/B07RS8B5HV/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber={}&sortBy=recent".format(num)

    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    for ratings in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-hook": "review"}):
        submission_date = ratings.find("span", {'data-hook':'review-date'}).text
        rating = ratings.find('i', attrs={"data-hook": "review-star-rating"}).text
        paid = ratings.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-color-success a-text-bold"})
        if paid:

         if paid.text in ratings.text:
             vine.append("Paid")
             date_list.append(submission_date)
             rating_list.append(rating)

             data = {'Rating': rating_list, 'Date': date_list, "Paid": vine}
        else:
            vine.append("Not-paid")

            date_list.append(submission_date)
            rating_list.append(rating)

            data = {'Rating':rating_list, 'Date':date_list, "Paid":vine}
        time.sleep(2)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          Date      Paid              Rating
0   2019-09-18  Not-paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
1   2019-09-13  Not-paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
2   2019-09-12      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
3   2019-09-11      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
4   2019-09-10  Not-paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
5   2019-09-10  Not-paid  2.0 out of 5 stars
6   2019-09-10      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
7   2019-09-09      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
8   2019-09-09  Not-paid  2.0 out of 5 stars
9   2019-09-08      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
10  2019-09-05      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
11  2019-09-01  Not-paid  2.0 out of 5 stars
12  2019-08-31      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
13  2019-08-25      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
14  2019-08-24  Not-paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
15  2019-08-22  Not-paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
16  2019-08-21      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
17  2019-08-20  Not-paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
18  2019-08-20      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
19  2019-08-18      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
20  2019-08-17  Not-paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
21  2019-08-17  Not-paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
22  2019-08-14  Not-paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
23  2019-08-12      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
24  2019-08-05      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
25  2019-08-05      Paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
26  2019-08-04      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
27  2019-08-04      Paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
29  2019-08-03      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
28  2019-08-03      Paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
..         ...       ...                 ...
80  2019-07-08      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
81  2019-07-08      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
82  2019-07-08      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
85  2019-07-07      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
83  2019-07-07      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
84  2019-07-07      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
87  2019-07-06      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
86  2019-07-06      Paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
88  2019-07-05  Not-paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
89  2019-07-05      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
90  2019-07-05      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
91  2019-07-05      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
92  2019-07-04      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
93  2019-07-04      Paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
94  2019-07-04      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
95  2019-07-04      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
96  2019-07-04      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
98  2019-07-03  Not-paid  3.0 out of 5 stars
97  2019-07-03      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
99  2019-07-01      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
100 2019-07-01      Paid  3.0 out of 5 stars
101 2019-07-01      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
102 2019-06-30      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
103 2019-06-29      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
104 2019-06-29      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
105 2019-06-28  Not-paid  1.0 out of 5 stars
106 2019-06-27      Paid  4.0 out of 5 stars
107 2019-06-27      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
108 2019-06-26      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars
109 2019-06-26      Paid  5.0 out of 5 stars

[110 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Not quire working. But I also notice there's something going on what is going on with the "if paid" indents?

Comment: If the element is present under parent tag then check the inner if item text val or go to else that is what if paid: all about.However I ran the code and it’s giving me both Not-paid and paid option.

Comment: Weird. I am not sure why mine is bugging. I also only get 20 reviews, all non-paid, compared to my own code, which gave me all 110 reviews.

Comment: You added the output, and it looks correct. I get mine in rows of 20. Not sure why we get so different results?

Comment: @doomdaam: No idea what you have done at your end.If you copy and paste entire code this should work as expected.I ran couple of times and getting 110 every time.

Comment: @doomdaam : If you just add `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}` this should work as well.

Comment: I literally just copy paste. Gotta figure out what's going on here. Thanks for the input! I use Spyder, python 3.7, can this interfere?

Comment: I did it. Thank you for your help. I think the fault was in the keyboard language. So when I manually typed your code in, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way (with bs4 4.7.1+) is to use :has and :not to do the exclusion up front. You then don't need the exclude field/flag. In the following I print out the reviewer name as a visual check (you will see that the paid reviewers names don't appear). I also adjust your loop to work properly and use `Session` for efficiency. I also use shorter more robust selectors.

css selectors are faster than `find` so I would probably change `find` lines to:

```
submission_date = review.select_one('[data-hook=review-date]').text
rating = review.select_one('[data-hook=review-star-rating]').text
```

---

Py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
rating_list = [] 
date_list = []

with requests.Session() as s:   
    for num in range(1,12):
        url = "https://www.amazon.com/Jabra-Wireless-Noise-Canceling-Headphones-Built/product-reviews/B07RS8B5HV/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber={}&sortBy=recent".format(num)
        r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

        for review in soup.select('.review:not(:has(.a-color-success))'):   
            submission_date = review.select_one('[data-hook=review-date]').text
            rating = review.select_one('[data-hook=review-star-rating]').text
            date_list.append(submission_date)
            rating_list.append(rating)
            print(review.select_one('.a-profile-name').text) #check 
    data = {'Rating':rating_list, 'Date':date_list}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: I'm an awe of this pseudo-selector `:has()`.

Comment: I've created a mesmerizing script in vba using rotation of proxies automatically taken from a free proxy website. The script is able to bypass any sort of banning except for captchas which appeared in the very first place. It is capable of scraping almost all the sites as long as the content are static other than google. Some day I'll send that to you.

Comment: @SIM I look forward to seeing it. Glad to see you using :has as well.

Comment: Looks interesting. Will be testing this tomorrow and will report back!